# My 'body' css background image is jumping in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a joomla website I'm developing. My body tag has an image background. When I reload a page or navigating to another page on Google Chrome, my main html is loaded first and then the background image of the body tag is added. So in each reloading, you see a jumping (or better say like a LED goes on and off) effect because first you see the body tag with its default background color and then the background image is added. Of course it happens very fast but I wanna solve this issue.
I kow the order of loading HTML elements in a page is different on Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. So How can I solve this issue on google chrome?!

My Css:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0.01em;
}    
html, ﻿body, div.MainWrapper {
    background:url('../images/common/bg.jpg') transparent repeat-x scroll center top;
}
```

Comment: Not even my background image, but all background images of other html elements on my pages are loaded after the whole page is loaded. Maybe I need a jquery to sync all loadings in the chrome!!!

Answer (score 1):

only apply to body

```
body {
    background:url('../images/common/bg.jpg') transparent repeat-x scroll center top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply; but it's not helping. The line that you suggested me to add, only make my page scroll on a fixed background. My problem is my page is jumping when I reload a page or navigate to a new page. In some pages, not only my background but also my background image of my other HTML elements are jumping.